Parametrization of Generalized Hyperbolic distribution in RUgarch
I'm working on a project about GARCH models, and I fitted a GARCH(1,1) to some data with the RUGarch package in R, assuming Generalized Hyperbolic distributions (GHYP). I believe RUGarch assumes the innovations must SWN, and the model outputs the following parameters for the distribution
skew=-0.960222, shape=0.250040 and
ghlambda=-3.970268
I am using Python for numerical computations of tail-indices and I would like to "transfer" the GHYP distribution with the parameters above to Python. I'd like to use scipy.stats.genhyperbolic.pdf() which takes the following parameters:
pdf(x, p, a, b, loc=0, scale=1)
and my problem is that I am having a hard time finding how to transcribe the parameters of RUGarch to the ones of SciPy. The documentation of both packages got me confused and I don't really know how to proceed. Anything would be greatly appreciated !

This question doesn't seem to be mathematical but rather programming-related. If you believe your problem is mathematical, please rephrase the question. Otherwise, there are other sites on StackExchange which are suitable for that.

How do you go from one parametrization to the other basically. RUgarch according to its documentation uses a Zeta-Rho parametrization, then converted to Alpha-Beta. But I'm having trouble converting it into the parameters required by SciPy.

Instead of trying to do it with SciPy, could you use the method here on StackOverflow?

I was finally able to figure out the parameterization, thanks for your help
